# Nested eachs in jQuery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

How can I get the parent $value on a nested `{{each}}`? I would prefer a "direct" solution, without having to create a 2nd template, and use it from the first one.

Comment: Rearrange your data then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do this: `${ parentItem.Name }`, if the parent item was called `parentItem` and the desired member variable was called `Name`.  Here is an example, based loosely on the movie example in the [jQuery API docs for `{{each}}`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/):

**Template:**

```
<li>
    Title: ${Name}.<br />
    {{each(i, edition) Editions}}
        ${i + 1}: <em>${edition.Name}. </em><br />
        Languages: <br />
        {{each(i, language) Languages}}
            ${language} (${$data.Name}, ${edition.Name}) <br />  
        {{/each}}
        <br />
    {{/each}}
</li>
```

**Data (only one item for this example):**

```
var movies = [
    {
        Name: "City Hunter",
        Editions: [
            {
                Name: "Original", 
                Languages: ["Mandarin", "Cantonese"]
            },
            {
                Name: "DVD",
                Languages: ["French", "Spanish"]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

**Result:**

```
Title: City Hunter.
1: Original.
Languages:
Mandarin (City Hunter, Original)
Cantonese (City Hunter, Original)

2: DVD.
Languages:
French (City Hunter, DVD)
Spanish (City Hunter, DVD)
```

In this example, the inner `{{each}}` is getting values from:

- The outer `{{each}}` with `${edition.Name}`
- The root template data with `${$data.Name}`