# Get value of parent for loop in jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get the value of the current element in the parent of a for loop using jQuery Templates?

Note: I must use jQuery and must use this [template](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl).

Example:

```
{{each firstList}}
   <h1>${$value}</h1> //value of current index in first loop
   {{each secondList}}
      <p>${$value}</p> //value of current index in second loop
      <strong>???</strong> //how do I reference the value of the first loop here?
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: What is the structure of `firstList` and `secondList` ?

Comment: I apologize for the late reply Laura, but I've found the answer in another post. Thank you for your time. @Laura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's already a post that resolves this question by using the `${ parentItem.Name }`.

Link here: [Nested eachs in jQuery template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508404/nested-eachs-in-jquery-template)